Protoc and GRPC in Java. avoid camelCase convention
I have compiled the health.proto for my Java application, using
protoc --java_out=...... --grpc-java_out=... -I=..... proto .....health.proto

Compiles OK and creates the required java classes.
The health.proto is directly grabbed from [grpc github repo][1]
In there, there are  2 rpc defined as :
 rpc Check(HealthCheckRequest) returns (HealthCheckResponse);
 rpc Watch(HealthCheckRequest) returns (stream HealthCheckResponse);

(Note capital C and W)
However, both methods have lost the Capitalization on the generated java  stubs, and they are now check() and watch() lowercase both.
As a result of the above, if I add a HealthStatusImpl as a service on my server, it can not be reached from another grpc component developed in Python which is trying to invoke
stub.Watch() and stub.Check()
(tests performed from a client written in Java, using lowercase versions, works as expected)
Is there any way to bypass this feature? As far as I can see, there is no:
https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/javatutorial/

The difference in capitalization should not prevent a separate Python project from invoking RPCs using Python capitalization norms.  It seems likely that there's some other bug in your Python.

Thanks @LouisWasserman.
Does it means that using  stub.Watch() from Python would correctly invoke HealthStatusImpl's watch() in java?

Yes, it should.

Indeed, There was an error elsewhere. Sorry for that.
It is clear that capitalization is not a problem when creating stubs in different languages.
Many thanks again Louis Wasserman
